# How to define variable in a function and return the data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create an program where I receive the number of COVID-19 patients from and API and use that data.

This is my code:

```
    import requests
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import timedelta

    date = str(date.today() - timedelta(days=1))
    country = 'india'
    def search(date, country):
        print("Showing Data For :", date)

        url = "https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/name"

        querystring = {"date-format":"undefined","format":"undefined","date":date,"name":country}

        headers = {
            'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
            'x-rapidapi-key': "286798d6demshcf160ec64afce22p11662bjsn40bdced08453"
            }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()

        data = response[0]
        data = data["provinces"]
        data = data[0]
        return data
    search(date, country)

    print("Total Cases In India :", data['confirmed'])
```

Whenever I execute the code I get an error.

This is the Error : NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: You're not capturing the return value of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the return value.

```
import requests
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

date = str(date.today() - timedelta(days=1))
country = 'india'


def search(date, country):
    print("Showing Data For :", date)

    url = "https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/name"

    querystring = {"date-format": "undefined", "format": "undefined", "date": date, "name": country}

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "286798d6demshcf160ec64afce22p11662bjsn40bdced08453"
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()

    data = response[0]
    data = data["provinces"]
    data = data[0]

    #THIS DATA VARIABLE DOES NOT EXIST OUTSITE OF THE FUNCTION
    return data

# HERE YOU NEED TO ASSIGN THE RETURN VARIABLE TO THE DATA VARIABLE
data = search(date, country)

print("Total Cases In India :", data['confirmed'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 print("Total Cases In India :", data['confirmed'])
```

This is outside the function and variable data is defined in the scope of function so it is not visible outside them. You should call the function and store it in the variable. Then use it in the print as @Nivardo did in the answer above.